# Web / Rest Api to get java dependency metadata

Tags: rest, maven, automation, metadata

I'm looking for some REST Api that provides metada information about java libraries.

My goal is to automate 3rd party dependencies approval process. 
I need following metadata about java jars:

1. Licence
2. Copyright
3. Home page url
4. Official repository url (this part is not required)

I was looking into Sonatype RepoManager Rest but it doesn't return such information

```
GET /service/rest/v1/components/{id}

{
  "id" : "bWF2ZW4tY2VudHJhbDo4ODQ5MWNkMWQxODVkZDEzNjYwYmUwMjE1MjI2NGUwZQ",
  "repository" : "maven-central",
  "format" : "maven2",
  "group" : "org.apache.httpcomponents",
  "name" : "httpcomponents-client",
  "version" : "4.3.5",
  "assets" : [ {
    "downloadUrl" : "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.3.5/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5.pom",
    "path" : "org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.3.5/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5.pom",
    "id" : "bWF2ZW4tY2VudHJhbDozZjVjYWUwMTc2MDIzM2I2YTFhOGUxOGQxZmFkOGM3Mw",
    "repository" : "maven-central",
    "format" : "maven2",
    "checksum" : {
      "sha1" : "95d80a44673358a5dcbcc2f510770b9f93fe5eba",
      "md5" : "f4769c4e60799ede664414c26c6c5c9d"
    }
  }, {
    "downloadUrl" : "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.3.5/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5.pom.sha1",
    "path" : "org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.3.5/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5.pom.sha1",
    "id" : "bWF2ZW4tY2VudHJhbDpmODk4YjM5MDNjYjk5YzU5ZDU3YjFlYjE0MzM1ZTcwMQ",
    "repository" : "maven-central",
    "format" : "maven2",
    "checksum" : {
      "sha1" : "6b98f5cef5d7102f8f45215bdcf48dc843d060af",
      "md5" : "f3b3ac640853fcb887621d13029a1747"
    }
  } ]
}
```

So, is there an easy way to get dependency metadata?

Comment: All the information you have mentioned are contained in the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: So, copyright information is not available in pom.xml, there is only Organization tag. Besides that those informations aren't mandatory and are not always available in poms.

Comment: The license is in the pom file but it might be necessary to read the parents to get those informations...The organization is something different.

Comment: Yes, I need both copyright and licence